# What's the next number in this sequence? 7, 30, 84, 81,?

Tags: number-sequence

I got this question in an online assessment for a job interview, and it's still puzzling me.

This is the sequence:

> 7, 30, 84, 81, ?

Possible answers are:

> -77, -93, 106, 73

Comment: Jesse I am curious what were the other answers like in the test? Was there alot or any of lateral thinking involved or were the answers based on mathematical formulas mainly?

Comment: Interpolating polynomial yields $-67$.

Comment: Possible solution: -67. Solved by finding matching function equation using a computer.